# Show five digits after decimal point in c++ but if there are 0 after decimal point don't print them

Tags: c++, decimal, cout, digits

The number must be displayed with exactly five digits after the decimal. If the number is 0 to display only 0 instead of 0.00000. If the number has zeros in his decimal recording only show numbers other than zero, for example 0.08500 instead of outputting 0.085
//s0 is my variable

```
if (s0==) cout<<"0"
else cout<<setiosflags(ios::fixed)<<setprecision(5)<<s0;
```

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you have (besides the illegal condition)? For some specific value of `s0` what is the expected and *actual* output?

Comment: it is expected : 0.085 but my code print: 0.08500

Comment: Do you only want to print "0" if s0 is exactly 0 or whenever your output would be "0.00000" i.e. if s0 happens to be <0.00001 ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << s0;
```

In your version `setiosflags(ios::fixed)` is forcing trailing zeros.

Comment: @ElizMazalova please mark this answer as accepted if it has answered your question. This removes it from the list of unanswered questions and enables other people to google it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It seems obvious, but could you use printf?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("%5.3f", 0.8500000000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question seems to be specific to c++. (also, cout, judging by the tags).

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily do it in C++ with the streams and << operator, because 0 is a special case.

Write a function

```
 std::string tonice(double x)
 {
    char buff[64];
    if(x == 0)
       sprintf(Buff, "0");
    else
       sprintf(buff, "%5.3f", x);
    return std;string(buff);

  }
```

Then

```
 cout << "The data is " << tonice(x) << " other bits and bats";
```

Answer (score 0):

std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << s0;
This is the best method for setting precision.